# Should we actively encourage use of JavaScript ES5+ features?

Tags: discussion

For at least three and a half years ECMAScript 5 has been the current version of JavaScript supported on mainstream browsers.  (IE9 was released March 14 2011).

I believe it's time that we were free to use ES5 features freely in our answers *without* feeling like we have to mention ES5 polyfills for older browsers.  Nor should we need to supply an ES3 version "just in case".  IMHO, if folks want to know how to use a particular ES5 function in IE8, that should just be a separate question in its own right.

Should we (could we?) do anything to proactively encourage idiomatic ES5 code instead?

Answer (score 20):

I've dropped mentioning ES5 polyfills for the past year or so. I used to link to the MDN page and mention polyfills or to direct polyfills. However, about a year ago I stopped doing it.

No one seemed to really care. In about 400 answers, I got maybe 3-4 "Would this work on IE" which prompted a polyfill link.

It's only an anecdote, and most of my answers focus on new features (Promises are a focus of mine, and those are built in only as of ES6 for example). However, I think we can learn from this.

- **If it's a question that has to do with old browsers** - mention polyfills. Encourage people to use them, and link to them. If the features are impossible to polyfill (for example getters) - no point in using those.
- **If it's a general question without compat issues** - use idiomatic code. Don't fear `Array#map` and in questions doing in AJAX doing `xhr.onload` instead of that clunky `.onreadystatechange` thing is perfectly fine.
- **If it's tagged jQuery** or there are other strong indicators of required old browser support - you might want to ask the OP if they're using jQuery/SomeLibrary because they have to support old browsers.

**Overall - the goal is to be useful** - using ES5 code should be done when it is more useful to the person asking the question and future readers than not doing it. This is the guideline I've gone by in my answers and it has been working out fine for me.